# How to ssh to a private ip via a public ip in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, ssh

I need to ssh to a server which is has a private ip 10.x.x.x via the public ip 50.x.x.x? How can I do that in mac terminal using the ssh command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
M = MacOS
P = Server with Public IP (50.x.x.x)
S = Server with Private IP (10.x.x.x)
```

So three systems?

If this is correct, you can use the 'P' server as a proxy with something like this from the commandline on M to ssh to S:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p 50.x.x.x" 10.x.x.x
```

This can be written into your .ssh/config so that you don't have to type it each time

```
Host 10.x.x.x
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p 50.x.x.x
```

Or it could be written as a type of 'Alias' so that you always refer to it by a short name:

```
Host S
    Hostname 10.x.x.x
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p 50.x.x.x
```

Then from M's commandline you can do

```
ssh S
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i only have the pem file for S and I don't have a pem file for P. When I tried your command I got a permission denied public key error. So do i also need to have the pem file for P?